# How to set the Media Name for an Epson printer in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set the Media Name to "Custom" for an Epson printer in a WinForms application?
I tried to set it using:

```cs
new PaperSize("Custom", Convert.ToInt32(width * 0.3937 * 100), Convert.ToInt32(height * 0.3937 * 100));
```

but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Is there a difference between your two `new PaperSize...` expressions? Why do you have an `asp.net` tag on this question?

Comment: sorry, I have set the paper type and page settings for the printer in my program, but it doesn't seem to take effect on the printer. The printer still prints in the default way. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us all your code, here's a working example:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;

PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
PaperSize customPaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", Convert.ToInt32(width * 0.3937 * 100), Convert.ToInt32(height * 0.3937 * 100));
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = customPaperSize;

// I'm not sure if you'll need this for a Sqaure Paper size? Try printing with and without this line.
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

Comment: No, there is no problem with the printing direction, but the content exceeds the preset width. It is normal to preview using PrintPreviewControl

Comment: I think there's a registry hack to bypass the PrintPreview but its not guaranteed to work on various OS's. Leave the preview in to try and save paper....

Comment: Thank you, what should I do?

Comment: [Edit] your question and include a screenshot. Someone with rep will allow it to show later and then we can see what you're dealing with exactly.